# How to exclude post-tag taxonomy for a custom post type?

Tags: taxonomy

Here is the code:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'wpas_ticket_type_args', array(
                'labels'              => $labels,
                'taxonomies'          => array('product'),
                'public'              => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => true,
                'query_var'           => true,
                'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => apply_filters( 'wpas_rewrite_slug', $slug ), 'with_front' => false ),
                'capability_type'     => 'view_ticket',
                'capabilities'        => $cap,
                'has_archive'         => true,
                'hierarchical'        => false,
                'public'              => true,
                'menu_position'       => null,
                'menu_icon'           => $icon,
                'supports'            => $supports,
                'taxonomies'          => array(),
                'template'            => $gutenburg_new_template
        ) );

        register_post_type( 'ticket', $args );
```

all variable like $labels, $cap is defined. It works fine. I added  `'taxonomies'          => array(),` and I can see post tag as shown below image:
[image]

I can add additional taxonomy like category by adding :

```
'taxonomies'=> array('category') but how can I exclude post tag as shown above image?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to unregister the post_tag taxonomy from the Custom Post Type.

```
function wpdocs_unregister_tags_for_posts() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_unregister_tags_for_posts' );
```

Update the `'post'` to your custom post type.

Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type/

Also, you've defined the following twice in your `$args`

```
'taxonomies'          => array('product'),
'taxonomies'          => array(),
```